# installing transmission on debian with docker, right trouble

Tags: shell, docker, debian, file-permissions

I am a biginner with docker, I try to make my transmission container work!

First I am running on a debian 8.1.
To make things work I created this 2 folder:

```
mkdir -p /opt/docker/transmission/config
mkdir -p /opt/docker/transmission/downloads
```

after this I added the "good" right:

```
chown -R root:docker /opt/docker
chmod -R 775 /opt/docker
```

At the end I tried to create my docker by doing this:

```
docker run -d \
    --net="host" \
    --name="Transmission" \
    -e USERNAME="root" \
    -e PASSWORD="mdp" \
    -v /opt/docker/transmission/config:/config \
    -v /opt/docker/transmission/downloads:/downloads \
    -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
    gfjardim/transmission
```

The command docker logs transmission gives:

> Couldn't save temporary file "/config/resume/myfile.resume.tmp.hYhTPF": No such file or directory

I guessed that the folder resume in config was not created so I created it, but I didn't work.

The message in transmission GUI is:

> unable to save resume file: permission denied

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce you errors using your commands. I suggest you delete your `/opt/docker/transmission/` directory and then run the `docker run` command.

Docker will take care of creating those repositories.

Comment: I follow your suggestion, I delete all the folders.
Re-run the command "docker run...", it created the folders. But it didn't solved the problem.
I am getting this error: 
[2015-09-01 13:19:42.269 CEST] Couldn't save temporary file "/config/resume/myfile.resume.tmp.3pMACv": No such file or directory (variant.c:1227)
I have a syncthing that work without any problems with files right. But with transmission I have a lot of trouble.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution for gfjardim/transmission container
But by changing container it worked directly.
I followed the dperson/transmission in the hub site, and it work perfectly.
Thanks for your help.